# connect kafka MSK to mongodb

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to connect mongodb to kafka using Kafka connect.

but I am using kafka MSK , no kafka confluent connectors can be used. Do you have any idea how to do it please ? 
Thanks.

Comment: "no kafka confluent connectors can be used" -- Why not?

Comment: May I ask on what you went for ? Currently trying to find the best go to solution for kafka and mongodb so as possibilities i see Confluent Cloud managed Kafka with Mongodb Atlas (and confluent connector) or AWS MSK with a custom connector for documentDB or so

Answer (score 2):

You would need to run the Kafka Connect worker yourself, and install the appropriate MongoDB connector in the worker. You can find a list of connectors at https://hub.confluent.io.